# How do I get forEach loop or .map() to return or show certain data after it's been changed via filters?

Tags: javascript, ejs

I'm relatively new to JavaScript. I don't know what I'm doing...

I've been taking Colt Steele's course. I know it's out-dated. I've been working with React, but I've gone back to the older material because I think it's important that I learn some things that are fundamental. I believe it will cripple me, if I don't know the basics...

I've been trying to build a real estate app, for my portfolio. I've set up a new server, and I've been trying to figure out the logic... How would I, once I've got an array of objects looping through a forEach or .map(), change this data with filters. I am doing this using EJS.

How do I get the listings to change, or certain listings to show and others not in EJS?

I placed my variable 'listings' inside of my 'app.js' file, at the top. I put my loop inside of my 'listings.ejs' file. That works fine. The loop and the data show in my 'ejs' file. But I don't even know where to start with how I would get any data I'm trying to change to show in the forEach or .map(). I put code inside of my script tag in my 'footer' 'partial' to capture the value of the 'select' and 'option' tags in my 'header' 'partial' and it returns 'null' in the console when ever I try to change the value in the drop-down. This error occurs in the 'listings.ejs' file.

```
// This is inside the 'app.js'

let listings = [
  {address: '251 North Bristol Avenue', image: "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1470770841072-f978cf4d019e", city: "Los Angeles", price: 220000},
  {address: '14 N Moore St', image: "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1498855926480-d98e83099315", city: "New York", price: 320000},
  {address: '129 W 81st St', image: "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1485343034225-9e5b5cb88c6b", city: "New York", price: 520000}
]

app.listen(3000, function() {
  console.log("Server has started!")
});
```

```html
<!-- This is inside the 'listings.ejs' -->

    <% listings.forEach(function(listing) { %>
      <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6">
        <div class="thumbnail">
          <img src="<%= listing.image %>">
          <div class="caption">
            <h4><%= listing.address %></h4>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    <% }) %>
```

Like I said, I wouldn't know where to start...

I don't know how I would populate my 'options' tag i.e. the 'select' tag with the cities that ARE available in the 'listings' variable. I assume looping through them using a forEach? And once I click it how to get it to affect what is happening in the forEach.

I also don't know how I would get my price 'asc' and 'dsc' to affect what is happening in the forEach.

```
filteredData = () => {
  let newData = list.filter((a, b) => {
    return b.price - a.price
  })
}
```

Bottom line is, I don't know how I would get any of my filter data from the 'partials' to show in my 'listings.ejs'' forEach loop when I change it...

Nor do I know where to put the code and/or how to somehow connect them. I'm sorry if this is basic...

Answer (score 0):

You need just to apply filter to your array and catch the result like this:

```
var words = ['spray', 'limit', 'elite', 'exuberant', 'destruction', 'present'];
const result = words.filter(word => word.length > 6);
console.log(result);
// expected output: Array ["exuberant", "destruction", "present"]
```

So for your case you just have to change your function passing your array:

```
filteredData = (list) => {
  let newData = list.filter((a, b) => {
    return a - b
  });
    console.log(newData);
  return newData;
}

let arr = [1, 5, 2, 12, 9, 8];
filteredData(arr);
```

Answer (score 0):

To sort the array you can make use of "sort" function in js, instead of using filter.

```
  filteredData = (list) => {
  let newData = list.sort((a, b) => {
    return b.price - a.price
  })
}
```